# WP Query Pagination not working on one template

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm having (yet) more trouble with WordPress pagination. It works on every page other than a custom taxonomy archive page, which, still has a custom loop in it due to the websites complexities.

But, I feel like it should still work because it's essentially the same queries running as on all my other pages, with a couple of minor differences.

At the moment, it gets the right URL for the page number, it just displays the 404 page.

Here's the code I have:

Pagination Function

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+5 || $i <= $paged-$range-5) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class='current'>".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
```

WP Query

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { 
    $paged = get_query_var('paged'); 
} else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page'); 
} else {
    $paged = 1; 
}


$args = array(  
    // general
    'post__in' => $postIDs,
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'paged' => $paged,

    'orderby' => 'post__in',
    'order' => 'ASC'

);


$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Pagination call after `endwhile` on page with custom query
`<?php pagination($pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>`

Any ideas why this might not be working when it works on other pages?

Comment: Shouldn't `<?php pagination($pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>` be `<?php pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>` ?

Comment: Hi, just tried this, gets the right URL, but takes me to the 404 page unfortunately.

Comment: How have you registered your custom taxonomy?

Comment: Yes. The taxonomy has been set up using the CTP UI plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)

Comment: If your site uses custom permalinks, you will need to flush your permalink structure after making changes to your taxonomies, or else you may see a "Page Not Found" error. Your permalink structure is automatically flushed when you visit Settings > Permalinks in your WordPress dashboard.

(http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

Answer (score 0):

I see code for pagination is ok, if you see 404 page cause have variables conflict in 1 of your plugins installed on site, im sure you did 1 customine to add new request variable in 1 other plugin but use wrong method so its make conflict.
I suggest you disable each plugin per time then test it on frontend so if pagination works you will know which plugin make conflict error.
THank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Then I realized the default posts per page option on settings page should be less than any custom posts_per_page in query_posts function. That's all. Weird, but that's the fact.

Comment: Hi, just changed this to 5 and still get the 404 page I'm afraid.

Comment: change it to 1 and try.

Comment: anyway wordpress has a bug with paginations. check this ticket. they'll fix it in next version.
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15551

Answer (score 0):

You mention you're querying a custom taxonomy but your query doesn't seem to query a custom taxonomy. Maybe try adding something like `'cars' => get_queried_object()->name` to your query args - where `cars` is the name of your custom taxonomy.

For example:

```
$args = array(
    'post__in'       => $postIDs,
    'post_type'      => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => 25,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'orderby'        => 'post__in',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'cars'           => get_queried_object()->name
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

**Note:** Untested but I am 99% sure `get_queried_object()->name;` gets the current taxonomy term name.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: This is true to be honest. The CTP is used for all countries/towns/cities in the world, as a way of generating pages for each. However, I have events that are located via their lat/long, rather than assigning them to the taxonomy. So technically the taxonomy is empty, I just wanted them there to generate the pages. May this be the issue?